# PPL task call in a while C++

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2013, ppl, cpprest-sdk

I'm working on a crossover remote working job test and i use Cpp Rest Casablanca.
I need to parse an XML file so i found on google this xml parser (it seems to be the fastest parser)

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/XmlLite-XML-node-writer-4472022a/sourcecode?fileId=51211&pathId=2033671260

However i need to change it because every time i have a potentially blocking I/O operation (like reading file for example) i have to create a task.
So i try to transform from this (just a litte piece of code)

```
  //read until there are no more nodes
while (S_OK == (hr = pReader->Read(&nodeType)))
{
    switch (nodeType)
    {
    case XmlNodeType_XmlDeclaration:
    wprintf(L"XmlDeclaration\n");
        if (S_OK != pReader->MoveToNextAttribute()) 
            break;
```

to something like this:

```
task<HRESULT> ReadNodeXML([&]()
{
    return pReader->Read(&nodeType);
});

//read until there are no more nodes
while (S_OK == (hr = ReadNodeXML.get()))
//while (S_OK == (hr = pReader->Read(&nodeType)))
{
    switch (nodeType)
    {
    case XmlNodeType_XmlDeclaration:
        wprintf(L"XmlDeclaration\n");
        if (S_OK != pReader->MoveToNextAttribute()) 
            break;
```

I'm actually studying PPL and casablanca but i didn't find many examples.
when i debug the code the first time ReadNodeXML.get() jump to ReadNodeXML task code but only one time so i'm not able to read others nodes and it loops.
Could someome explain what is wrong because after reading lots of doc i suspect to completely rewrite the code in a sort of recursively way.